# How to determine the container id or image name of an unknown docker volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, grafana, docker-volume

Please how do I determine the **container id or image** name of an **unknown docker volume?**
For example I was able to find the list of docker volumes by running the command '**docker volume ls'** but unfortunately when I was building some of the images I didn't mount a specific volume so most of my containers were built without a volume name. some of the examples of volumes with unknown names are listed below

**3199e3e4f3c2b79f04b84523959cb250223a229fca2ba16540cdbfd77762a552
c1cba1883daed381d83d9940d48e5f5aceed327614c58dc4bfa3cd7a6849274f
f2545f7cdef79e8c59dd8fc2a6d6de83876231554a738d25fe1f61f93c6b3eb9
f9cce0cfdd8ef8bae1e19aa41864e25f074929863a771b0ec729a119e2e880f7**

**Please how to determine the container id or image name of an unknown docker volumes**

How can I determine which of the volumes is for MYSQL, JENKINS, PROMETHEUS for example??

**REASON FOR MY QUESTION**

I am trying to enable alerts on Grafana so I can get a notification via email but I got this error message

****"For email alerts I get this message. SMTP not configured, check your grafana.ini config file’s [smtp] section"****

This means that I have to edit the grafana.ini config file which is mounted in the docker grafana volume but I am not able to do this.

Please I will appreciate your help.

Thanks

Comment: This question doesn't quite make sense; a volume could be attached to multiple containers, or none, and Docker doesn't really know what's in the volume besides "there's some files".  If you need to edit a configuration file then injecting it via a bind mount will be a better approach than storing it in an opaque named volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use:

```
docker ps -a --filter volume={{reference}}
```

Example:

```
docker ps -a --filter volume=3199e3e4f3c2b79f04b84523959cb250223a229fca2ba16540cdbfd77762a552
```

Answer (score 1):

To see which volume is mapped into which container you can try:

```
sudo docker ps -a --format '{{ .ID }}' | xargs -I {} docker inspect -f '{{ .Name }}{{ printf "\n" }}{{ range .Mounts }}{{ printf "\n\t" }}{{ .Type }} {{ if eq .Type "bind" }}{{ .Source }}{{ end }}{{ .Name }} => {{ .Destination }}{{ end }}{{ printf "\n" }}' {}
```

This lists all containers and the volumes attached to it.

I would recommend to host the grafana.ini file externally. Not necessarily via a volume but via file bind and tell grafana via environment variable where to find the grafana.ini. This gives you direct access to the file outside of the container. Here is the part of the docker command.

```
-v /data/docker/volumes/grafana-config/grafana2.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana2.ini \
-e "GF_PATHS_CONFIG=/etc/grafana/grafana2.ini" \
```

The command above will show you something like this:

```
/grafana
    bind /data/grafana/grafana-config/grafana2.ini => /etc/grafana/grafana2.ini
    volume grafana-storage => /var/lib/grafana
```

Comment: Sorry for bothering you once again)

Initially I just ran the Grafana docker with this command and didn't use docker compose so my question is how can I add this without removing my current docker container running. 

-v /data/docker/volumes/grafana-config/grafana2.ini:/etc/grafana/grafana2.ini \
-e "GF_PATHS_CONFIG=/etc/grafana/grafana2.ini" \

because I have made other Setups on the Grafana and wouldn't like to loose it? I have other datasources on it and I won't like to rebuild everything from scratch.

Sorry if the question seems lame, I'm kind of new to docker.

Comment: I'm not aware of a method how to reconfigure the container to connect volumes/binds afterwards. Regarding the data/configuration in the container I would go for a backup/restore approach using a) grafana backup ( https://grafana.com/docs/grafana/latest/installation/upgrading/#backup) or b) copy the files from the container to the host using docker cp (docker cp <containerId>:/file/path/within/container /host/path/target)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to work with Grafana volumes (actually, current official Grafana images don't have any volume by default). You can configure Grafana with env variables. They have syntax `GF_<grafana ini section>_<upper case properties>`.

`grafama.ini` config:

```
#################################### SMTP / Emailing #####################
[smtp]
enabled = true
```

can be achieved by Docker container env variable:

```
GF_SMTP_ENABLED: true
```

In theory you can also use volumes and ovewrite default container `/etc/grafana/grafana.ini` file with your own customized `grafana.ini`.